# How to keep the order in Enum list in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, enums, primeng

I created a enum list and want to use this as a dropdown in angular but the list automaticly orders my list instead of showing it as my order written as enum.

my enum:

```
    export enum Cars {
      VOLVO= "Volvo",
      AUDI = "Audi",
      VOLKSWAGEN = "Volkswagen",
      NISSAN = "Nissan"
    }
```

output on dropdown:

- Audi
- Nissan
- Volkswagen
- Volvo

ts file:

```
    carlist: Cars;
    car: Car;
```

my html file for dropdown:

```
      <p-dropdown [options]="carsList | keyvalue"
              [(ngModel)]="car.name" optionLabel="value" optionValue="key"
              placeholder="Choose"></p-dropdown>
```

Is there a way to keep the order in my dropdown as provided in my Enum file

I already tried to look for answers on stackoverflow and other forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`KeyValuePipe` documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe#description)

> The output array will be ordered by keys.

To customize the sorting, you need to provide the `compareFn`.

```
<p-dropdown
  [options]="carlist | keyvalue: unsort"
  [(ngModel)]="car.name"
  optionLabel="value"
  optionValue="key"
  placeholder="Choose"
></p-dropdown>
```

```
unsort = (a, b) => 0;
```

---

Alternatively, you can convert the Enum into array to guarantee the sequence.

```
carlist: any[] = Object.entries(Cars).map((v, k) => ({ key: k, value: v }));
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jg8dy6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fdropdown-basic-demo.html)